# Using Compact Support to write function as integral

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

If we have $u \in C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ then why does we require the compact support of $u$ in order to write:

$u(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_{i}}u_{x_{i}}(x_{1},…,x_{i-1},y_{i},x_{i+1},..,x_{n})dy_{i}$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Compact support guarantees the integral converges.

Comment: Okay thanks for responses. I thought the fundamantal theorem in that form applied to single variable functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be required in order to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FT1).

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus requires that $f$ be continuous on a closed compact set $[a,b]$, since $u$ is continuous and has a compact support we can evaluate the integral over the support which is closed and compact using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Just an idea. In fact since the $\text{supp}u$ is closed and bounded we can find such an $a$ and $b$ such that $\text{supp} u \subset [a,b]$ and then apply the first theorem of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: If you could elaborate, that would be a good thing to do. As it stands, it offers little in the way of an answer to the question.